# Is the square of a primitive cohomology class always primitive?

Tags: cohomology, smooth-manifolds, 3-manifolds

Let $M$ be a closed manifold (in my case $\dim M=3$).
Take $\alpha\in H^1(M;\mathcal{Or})$, where $\mathcal{Or}$ is the orientation local system for $M$ with coefficients $\mathbb Z$.

Suppose $\alpha$ is primitive (i.e. it cannot be devided by any integer $>1$).
Also suppose that its square $\alpha^2\in H^2(M;\mathbb Z)$ is nonzero.
**Is $\alpha^2$ necessarily primitive?**

In particular, can one find $M$ and primitive $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^2\ne0$ but $\alpha^2\equiv0\pmod2$?

Comment: Yes. Take $M=\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1$, and $\alpha =\operatorname{pr}_1^*\eta + \operatorname{pr}_2^*\eta$, where $\eta $ is a generator of $H^1(\mathbb{S}^1,\mathbb{Z})$. Then $\alpha $ is primitive but $\alpha ^2=2\operatorname{pr}_1^*\eta \cdot\operatorname{pr}_2^*\eta$.

Comment: @abx I think in your example $\alpha^2=0$, just note that $\mathrm{pr}^*_1\eta\cdot\mathrm{pr}^*_2\eta=-\mathrm{pr}^*_2\eta\cdot\mathrm{pr}^*_1\eta$

Comment: since $K(\mathbb Z,1)\approx S^1$, the square of any integer 1-cohomology class is zero

Comment: Oops, you are right, sorry.

Comment: What happens if you evaluate $\alpha^2$ on the Poincaré dual of $\alpha$ in $H_2(M;\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean by primitive, since $H^*(G,M)$ has no obvious comultiplication.

Comment: @DaveBenson  (i.e. it cannot be devided by any integer $>1$)

Comment: In the case that $M$ is orientable, $\alpha^2=0$. $\alpha \in H^1(M;\mathbb{Z})$ is realized by the pullback of a class $H^1(S^1)\to H^1(M)$ by Brown representability, and hence its square is zero.